# Why this question is nonlinear?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, nonlinear-system

Why this equation is nonlinear? 
If this equation is not linear, then what terms make this equation a nonlinear equation?

[image]

Comment: It looks linear to me... But maybe when they say "nonlinear radial diffusivity equation", it's not the equation that's non-linear but the diffusivity in some sense?

Comment: Probably because of $\frac{1}{r}$, which is nonlinear with respect to $r$.